# Markup Extensions, XAML's way of incorporating procedural programming?

Tags: wpf, xaml, markup, declarative

Can one say that Markup Extensions are XAML's way of incorporating procedural programming? What do you think the limitations of this statement are?

For example if you compare it pure XML, the Markup extensions are like "action elements" in a way, they are not quite part of the object tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Markup Extensions are just a more in-place way of describing what can be done by making more extensive use of tags (so their usage is declarative as hell):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Foo}">
```

is equivalent to

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
   <Binding Path="Foo">
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

As for Extensions in general...see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx). The {}-Syntax just dictates the compiler to use an instance of the corresponding extension type to handle the code in between. This, of course, is object oriented code and never not procedural in no way ever ever. Believe it or not - even people at M$ know how to code decently!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's purely declarative.  It is in no way procedural.

Comment: but behind the scenes, aren't markup extensions procedural code, or am I messing something up?

Comment: The way the compiler (and its extensions) may be implemented imperatively, that doesn't make the XAML markup itself an imperative programming language.  You describe how your windows look like, what properties they have, what items are in resource dictionaries, you never write out _how_ the windows get drawn, how the properties are set, how the items are placed in the resource dictionaries.  The markup extension is just an extension, you are still declaring that you are using them, not how they should be implemented.

Comment: I see what you are saying, what I was thinking of is if you compare it pure XML, the Markup extensions are like "action elements" in a way, they are not quite part of the object tree.